# Linear transformations using custom coordinates and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have the following question here:

> In $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $L$ be the line spanned and oriented by $\mathbf{v}=(−3,2,4)$, and let $R$ be the rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ through the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ about the $\mathbf{v}$ oriented line $L$ according to the Right Hand Rule.

> Further, let $P:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the vector $n=(-2\sqrt{29}-32,2-7\sqrt{29},2\sqrt{29}-25)$.

> Find the vector $\mathbf{z}$ which results from first rotating $\mathbf{x}=(2,7,−2)$ via $R$, and then projecting the rotated vector via $P$.

I know that I have to use custom coordinates here but I have no idea how to set up the matrices here. Can someone please help out here? I really want to understand the process behind how the transformations are set up here. I know how to use change of basis but not when the transformations are so strange.

Comment: You do know how to do it. Those two horrible vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Fair enough? How do I go from there though? I have no idea how to set up the matrices.

The answer below is unfortunately incorrect :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a computational disaster, but here's how you set it up (and let a computer do the arithmetic).

Let $v_1 = v/\|v\|$, $v_2=n/\|n\|$, and $v_3 = v_1\times v_2$. Then $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$. Let $Q$ be the matrix whose column vectors are $v_1,v_2,v_3$. (Because your first linear map is a rotation, you need an orthonormal basis for the plane orthogonal to $L$ — or at least a basis whose vectors have the same length. So we just go orthonormal for the whole thing.)

The matrix for $R$ in the convenient basis is
$$A_1 = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right].$$
The matrix for $P$ in the convenient basis is
$$A_2 = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right].$$
Thus, the matrix for $P\circ R$ in the convenient basis is
$$A=A_2A_1 = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right].$$
The change-of-basis formula tells us that the matrix for $P\circ R$ with respect to the standard basis is given by
$$B = QAQ^{-1} = QAQ^\top.$$
Calculate that and then multiply by your given vector.

Comment: Hey. So a follow up question. Why are you rotating and reflecting about the x axis? The rest of this makes since. You multiplied $A_1$ and $A_2$ to get the overall transformation and you can take the transpose instead of the inverse since you have an orthogonal matrix.

Also, what what the reason for taking the cross product?

Comment: In the new coordinate system, $L$ is the $x$-axis and the plane is the $xz$-plane (with normal line the $y$-axis). I used the cross product as the easiest way to get the third basis vector orthogonal to the first two and also a unit vector. :)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Why are you saying $L$ is the $x$-axis though? What's stopping me from making it the $z$-axis or some other axis? What was the reason for making this choice?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Choose any order of the standard basis vectors you want.

Comment: Perfect! That clears up the rest of my doubts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know what you're studying precisely, but some of my YouTube lectures on linear algebra and multivariable calculus/analysis might be of interest to you at some point, so check them out. (The link is in my profile.)

Answer (score 1):

We don't need matrix transformations for this case. We see that $\langle v, n \rangle = 0$, $\langle v, x \rangle = 0$, and therefore $v\perp n, v \perp x$. (Note that $\langle n, x \rangle \neq 0$). Let $\hat v$ and $\hat n$ indicate the unit vectors along $v$ and $n$ directions.

In 3 dimensions, rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is easy. you take the cross product. Lte $R_{v,\theta}(x)$ indicate the rotation of $x$ by $\theta$ about $\hat v$  Then let $y = R_{\hat v,\theta}(x)$, but this is just $y = \hat v\times x$.

Notice that $y$, like $x$ is perpendicular to $\hat v$. Then the projection of $y$ onto a plane perpendicular to $\hat n$, still keeps it perpendicular to $\hat v$. In other words, if
$z$ is the projection of $y$ onto the space perpendicular to $\hat n$. Then $z$ is  perpendicular to $\hat v$. Further, by definition it is perpendicular to $\hat n$.

Now a vector perpendicular to both $\hat n$ and $\hat v$ is given by $c(\hat v\times \hat n)$ for some constant c, which we now need to find. This is simply the projection of $y = \hat v\times x$ onto the line $c(\hat v\times \hat n)$, or in other words, the dot product onto the unit vector along $c(\hat v\times \hat n)$. Explicitly, $c = \frac{\langle \hat v\times x , \hat v\times \hat n\rangle}{||\hat v\times \hat n||^2}$ and $\boxed{z = \left\langle \hat v\times x , \frac{\hat v\times \hat n}{||\hat v\times \hat n ||}\right\rangle\frac{\hat v\times \hat n}{||\hat v\times \hat n ||}}$

Comment: I tried doing what you put but this isn't working. I thoroughly checked my calculations too :( .

Comment: I tried the following on python and obtained:
\begin{align*}
v &= np.array([-3,2,4]);\\
x &= np.array([2,7,-2];\\
n &= np.array([-2*sqrt(29)-32,2-7*sqrt(29),2*sqrt(29)-25]);\\
y &= np.cross(v,x);\\
zprime &= np.cross(v,n);\\
zprime &= zprime/np.linalg.norm(zprime);\\
z &= np.dot(y,zprime)*zprime\\\\
& $z =[-10.61483519,  19.84807682, -17.88516481]$ \\
& I\ checked\ that : z.dot(v) = 0; z.dot(n) =0
\end{align*}
What do you expect as the answer (different from what you got)?

Comment: I got the same thing as you but supposedly, that's incorrect. The question won't tell me what the right answer is unfortunately. To be very clear, here is the question in full.

https://imgur.com/a/kqGRwDq

You are supposed to put the exact numbers. I did that and I got the same decimal representation as you.

Comment: @FutureMathperson: can you try 1) making v and n unit norm before starting?
\begin{align*}
v &= np.array([-3,2,4]);\\
v &= v/np.linalg.norm(v)\\
x &= np.array([2,7,-2];\\
n &= np.array([-2*sqrt(29)-32,2-7*sqrt(29),2*sqrt(29)-25]);\\
n &= n/np.linalg.norm(n)\\
y &= np.cross(v,x);\\
zprime &= np.cross(v,n);\\
zprime &= zprime/np.linalg.norm(zprime);\\
z &= np.dot(y,zprime)*zprime\\\\
& z = [-1.97112541,  3.68569534, -3.32119173]\\
\end{align*}
Also 2) please try the negative of this number z?

Comment: I tried another method and unfortunately got it wrong but I can compare with this next week after the answers are out. I'm sorry :( .